# How to add Forms.DataVisualization.Charting to .NET Core Console Application

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I'm trying to create a chart in my console application. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553435/how-to-draw-chart-based-on-datatable-from-console-application) link can help me out with that. However, I don't have the namespace Forms in the namespace System.Windows. Can someone tell me how I can add that?

I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx) link that can help me out with that, but I don't know where to find the dll file.

Thanks.

Comment: Right click your references ==> add references ==> .NET tab look for System.Windows.Forms

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa Thanks for your reply. I cannot find the .NET tab you are talking about. This is the window I get when I press 'Add reference': https://imgur.com/a/cmu3mKX

Comment: Oh im not familiar with the VS2015 and above, just poke around in there and you'll find a window that lists the .NET references

Comment: @Zohir: The question is about .Net Core.

Comment: You aren't using Visual studio as an Editor ?

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa I am. Visual Studio Professional 2017.

Comment: So what i said is exactly what that link you provided says also in the References window, it should list all the .NET Core references if not look around in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry .net Core does not include windows forms.  .net Core is cross platform and windows forms is not supported because it runs on windows, Linux, and Mac.  The only form of UI is asp.net core which probably not what you are looking for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/

Comment: Despite this is still under construction, try this out:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization

I'm going to use it shortly, but I don't know when.

This could be another alternative... 

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit/